# Lua: How to Loop Through a non-Fixed Domain

Tags: loops, plot, lua

I usually use Lua to generate a data file that contains the coordinates of a curve whose expression is known. Then I plot the curve with other programs.

However, I also want to plot curves obtained by making a parameter vary in the expression of the first plot.

As an example, I would like to plot powers in the form of `y=x^1`, `y=x^1.5`, `y=x^2`, etc where the parameter I am talking about is the exponent (i.e., 1, 1.5, 2, etc).

Here I post an example of my usual work-flow (I hope the code explains itself better than I would):

```
-- test.lua
function POWER(x, y)
   return x^y
end

local xmin = 0 -- x: the abscissa
local xmax = 10
local xstep = 0.1

local ymin = 1 -- y: the parameter
local ymax = 2
local ystep = 0.5

local A = {}
local ix = 1 -- dummy variable to index A as an array
for I = xmin, xmax, xstep do
   A[ix] = {}
   A[ix].x = I
   A[ix].y = {}
   for J = ymin, ymax, ystep do
      table.insert(A[ix].y, POWER(I, J))
   end
   ix = ix + 1
end

local Out = io.stdout
--local Out = io.open("powerOUT.dat", "w")
Out:write("  x        x^1      x^1.5        x^2\n") -- from here on out I have to adjust things manually if I change ymin, ymax or ystep
for _, v in ipairs(A) do
   Out:write(string.format("%5.2f %10f %10f %10f\n", 
               v.x, v.y[1], v.y[2], v.y[3]))
end
```

and here an excerpt of what I get:

```
    x        x^1      x^1.5        x^2
 0.00   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
 0.10   0.100000   0.031623   0.010000
 0.20   0.200000   0.089443   0.040000
 0.30   0.300000   0.164317   0.090000
 ...
```

The issue with `xmin`,...,`ymin`,... is that I would like to make the procedure “automatic“ (i.e., I would like to change the value of some of these variables and have the data file change accordingly.) As of now, the procedure is automatic with the abscissa `x` (I can change the domain and the number of samples), but not with the parameter `y` (see the code I posted.)

So the question is: **How can I add columns to my data file when I change the value of the `y`-variables without manually adjusting the output?**

In this example, this question translates to: **How can I change (say) `ymax` and `ystep` to `ymax=5` and `ystep=0.25` without manually changing the `:write` statements at the end of the script?**

*N.B. Also the first line of the data file should be adjusted according to the new values.*

This is what I would like to get:

```
    x     x^1.00     x^1.25     x^1.50     x^1.75     x^2.00     x^2.25     x^2.50     x^2.75     x^3.00     x^3.25     x^3.50  ...   
 0.00   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ...
 0.10   0.100000   0.056234   0.031623   0.017783   0.010000   0.005623   0.003162   0.001778   0.001000   0.000562   0.000316 ...
 0.20   0.200000   0.133748   0.089443   0.059814   0.040000   0.026750   0.017889   0.011963   0.008000   0.005350   0.003578 ...
 0.30   0.300000   0.222025   0.164317   0.121608   0.090000   0.066607   0.049295   0.036482   0.027000   0.019982   0.014789 ...
...
```

As a side note, I admit that my procedure may not be optimal, so any suggestions are welcome. The general idea behind my work-flow is that I store all the data in a single array because it is simple to print the results I get in the “right order” using `ipairs()`.

Comment: Is the question how to print out the lines when you don't know how many `y` values you are going to have? If so then the answer is likely just a loop for that too.

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you're asking. What does automatic mean here? Would you like to be able to add a new column for a new y value, like 2.5 and have that column added to the file? An example of what you want the code to look like and the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @rpattiso: I would like to be able to change ymax and ystep to say ymax=5 and ystep=0.25 and have the relative columns added to the output without having to manually correct the ":write" statements at the end of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, because the number of columns may change, we can use a loop to iterate through all the columns and print column by column rather than line by line. Just replace the output section with the code below and change ymin, ymax and ystep to whatever values you want. Printing as you go would also be another option.

```
Out:write("pos    ")
for y = ymin, ymax, ystep do
      Out:write(string.format("y=%-5.2f     ", y))
end
Out:write("\n")
for _, v in ipairs(A) do
   Out:write(string.format("%5.2f ", v.x))
   for _, y in ipairs(v.y) do
      Out:write(string.format("%10f ", y))
   end
   Out:write("\n")
end
```

Comment: Perfect! I have just one doubt: as I have data file with thousands of values, are there problems regarding the performance given the fact that `Out:write()` is issued a _lot_ of times?

Comment: @PierPaolo Your OS will buffer your calls to write, it wont write out to file every call just when the buffer is full, or a newline will usually flush it too.